# Accessing main Activity objects from inside the ViewModel observer

Tags: android, viewmodel

Have the EventViewModel defined.

Changes are observable inside an Activity having the mObject defined:

```
Object mObject
EventViewModel eventModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    eventModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(EventViewModel.class);
    eventModel.getEvent().observe(this, event -> {

    //can't access the mObject here
    event.val = mObject.val;

};
}
```

The error shown is like:" 'this' is not available here" on call to mObject inside the .observe clause.

So my question is how can I access the Activity object from inside the ViewModel observer?

Comment: For example: "MainActivity.this"

Comment: MainActivity.this.mObject does not work .... Error msg is the same

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Class fields are accessible inside lambda expressions.

Comment: Not on my box :) Do you have ViewModel experience ??

Comment: Your snippet has mismatched parens and braces, and `event` appears to be both a class member and a local variable name. Please post more complete code.

Comment: Now it looks better ...

Answer (score 0):

So it was the misleading debugger msg ... @SaeedMasoumi was right, while my mind was stacked on debugger msg saying the 'this' is not accessible .. while it is! Just debugger shows is not ....